# 'Start Rollout To Production' button disabled after completing all gray points

Tags: android, publish, disabled-control

I have to publish a new app, but the button for release is disabled.

I did everything, all the required parts are filled and marked as 'Item ready to publish', but I still can't publish my app.

[image]

Any idea what I did wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to address the warning?

Comment: The warning it's about optimization, about using Android App Bundle to optimize the app.